# How to order Dictionary (or similar Collection) by key AND value?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

Is it possible to order dictionary by values (descending) and when the values are equal order them by keys (ascending)?

Example:

> Unordered:
>  (key, value)
>  C, 8
>  B, 8
>  A, 5
>  D, 11
>   F, 8
>
> Ordered:
>  (key, value)
>  D, 11
>  B, 8
>  C, 8
>  F, 8
>  A,
>   5

In that example the keys B, C, D has the same values. When I order the dictionary by values then these keys wont be in ascending order. How can I do this? Do I have to use something else than dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

When you enumerate a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, you get back a bunch of `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`... specifically `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` *is* `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, so you can use Linq over this (unordered) sequence:

```
var orderedKeyValuePairs =
     myDic.OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Value).ThenBy(kv => kv.Key);
```

Don't bother storing your ordered values back into a Dictionary as a Dictionary has no implicit sort order.

Comment: I would also add that if you are going to access this ordered pairs multiple times you put a .ToList() on the end of it.   :)

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<T,U>` is internally unordered.  You can fetch the values out in a specific order via LINQ, however:

```
var ordered = theDictionary.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Key);

// To print your ordered list
foreach(var entry in ordered)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
```